# track editor with "snap to track" function

Tags: openstreetmap

I need an editor (preferably Linux) which can load OSM maps and allows me to draw (hiking) tracks on it which I want to export as GPX. But I do not want to draw them free-hand but instead would like to have the editor automatically snap my drawn track to the nearest OSM track. The idea is to export arbitrary tracks which follow existing OSM tracks.

Does anyone know an application that is capable of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share how you solved this problem? I'm also looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still haven't found a suitable tool, then try [QLandkarteGT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qlandkartegt). It supports three types of maps 'Raster', 'Vector' and 'Streaming'. For the 'snap to road' feature to work you need to install a 'Vector' map and use while you're creating your track. Check also QLandkarteGT [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/qlandkartegt/index.php?title=Adding_maps) on adding maps.

Comment: I solved my problem otherwise, but thanks anyway. I'll keep it in mind.