# How do I obtain the coordinates along GMaps directions?

Tags: google-maps, gps, geocoding, kml

I want to create an online map for a hiking trail, and I have been using my smartphone to collect coordinates from it.

I have many questions regarding what's good practice when it comes to making such tracks, but for starters: *it would look much neater if I could edit the readings so that they are right on top any roads in Google Maps.* How can I achieve this?
EDIT: I want to find the coordinates that will make a track along a road look exactly as if I'm using snapping/directions even when I'm not.

I've tried tools such as QLandkarte GT and Viking, and with the latter I was able to manually remove excess coordinates and move the remaining ones so that they're exactly on top of roads (inside Viking, using OpenStreetMap). However when I load the edited .kml-file in Google Maps, the roads seem to be in slightly different places and the result is hardly better than before editing.

I tried using the hack that exports GMaps directions as .gpx, thinking I could insert Google's own coordinates along the roads. But the exported file only had coordinates at the turning points with straight lines between these.

QLandkarte GT [supposedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625439/track-editor-with-snap-to-track-function) has a snap-to-road feature (see answer in link), but I haven't found it and I also don't know how to obtain a vector map of the area.

Then there's Google Earth which people seem to use for this, but again I can't find any track editing features (in the free version).

**In short**:
How do I edit my existing tracks so that they match roads in GMaps...
OR
How can I obtain new tracks representing roads in GMaps...

...so that the resulting track is as smooth as Google's own directions or other professional GPS-data, when displayed in GMaps?

Comment: I believe your question actually asks about how to snap list of coordinates (track, path, polyline) to nearest street. One of numerous close answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9545729/151641 I'd suggest to search first and reformat your question to make the problem clearer (in case snappingis not what you are after).

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I couldn't find those questions. I'll look through them and see if snapping means I can actually get the updated, "snapped" coordinates, which is what I want.

Comment: You should be careful. Any attempts to download the coordinates might violate the Google Maps terms of service. Read the terms carefully to make sure you're compliant. Alternately, just use the Google Maps API for your directions.

Comment: @ManoMarks Thanks for the warning, I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's possible to get these coordinates from Google Maps after all, exporting the directions polyline. I'm not sure how, it seems to involve adding the parameter output=dragdir to the link.

Anyway there's a tool called [GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com) that can create a .kml-file with the wanted coordinates.

Edit: Will accept my own answer as long as it's the only one, but I would still like to know more.